# Blocking Queue - optionally block the reader/writer for a certain period of time

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

I'm developing a class to queue a given number of elements where the reading thread pops and the writing thread pushes them. If the queue is empty the reader blocks and if the queue is full the writer blocks aswell. But after that the writing and reading threads should optionally block for a certain period of time. Can someone please explain if is there a perfect way to do this requirement?

```
template<typename T>
class Queue
{
private:
    mutable std::mutex mut;
    std::queue<T> queue;
    std::condition_variable condNotEmpty;
    std::condition_variable condNotFull;
    int _count; 
    int max_size;
    int idx;
public:
    Queue(int size){
        max_size = size;
    }

    void push(T new_value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);

        /* initialize random seed: */
        srand (time(NULL));
        /* generate secret number between 1 and 3: */
        idx = rand() % 3 + 1;

        condNotFull.wait_for(lk,std :: chrono :: milliseconds ( 20 ),[this]{
            if ((_count == max_size)) {
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
            
        });

        queue.push(new_value);
        _count++;
        condNotEmpty.notify_one();

    }
    T pop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);

        /* initialize random seed: */
        srand (time(NULL));
        /* generate secret number between 1 and 3: */
        idx = rand() % 3 + 1;


        condNotEmpty.wait_for(lk, std :: chrono :: milliseconds ( 15 ),[this]{
            if(queue.empty()){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        });


        auto value=queue.front();
        queue.pop();
        _count--;
        condNotFull.notify_one();
        
        return value;
    }

    int Count(){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        return queue.size();
    }

    int Size(){
        return max_size;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::timed_mutex` and it's methods `try_lock_for` and `try_lock_until` for try to lock for/until a certain period of time.

Also it would probably be meaningful to reflect this API to your Queue with methods like `tryPush`, `tryPop` or `tryPushFor`, `PushUntil`, `tryPopFor`, `tryPopUntil`, etc. and leave push/pop do the blocking operations as is.

In your code you should also check the **return status** of `wait_for` call: it can be `std::cv_status::timeout` or `std::cv_status::no_timeout`, depending if condition variable was notified or timeout expired.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @StPiere ! I have to use this "scheme" but I thought that the **std::condition_variable:wait_for** would do the trick. Maybe I am not fully understanding how to use it.

Comment: You also need the check the status of wait_for call, because it can be timeout or no_timeout. see update.